# Lobby system on Unity Netcode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a lobby system for my game so that players would go to a match. This system exists as an entity. I have a running server, clients are connecting to it, and as soon as two clients click the "Ready" button, they will be transferred to the field of battle. This should ideally be, but nothing happens, no errors, nothing. I wrote a log so that after the user clicks "Ready" in the console it says "Player x is ready", but gives a warning in the screenshot

[image].

Tell me what the problem is.
I will attach the lobby code.

```
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace vsamomdeletak.Scripts.Networking
{
    public class LobbyUI : NetworkBehaviour
    {
        private NetworkList<LobbyPlayerState> lobbyPlayers;

        private void Awake()
        {
            lobbyPlayers = new NetworkList<LobbyPlayerState>();
        }

        public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
        {

            if (IsServer)
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += HandleClientConnected;
                NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += HandleClientDisconnect;

                foreach (NetworkClient client in NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList)
                {
                    HandleClientConnected(client.ClientId);
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();


            if (NetworkManager.Singleton)
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback -= HandleClientConnected;
                NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback -= HandleClientDisconnect;
            }
        }

        private bool IsEveryoneReady()
        {
            if (lobbyPlayers.Count < 2)
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach (var player in lobbyPlayers)
            {
                if (!player.IsReady)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void HandleClientConnected(ulong clientId)
        {
            var playerData = ServerGameNetPortal.Instance.GetPlayerData(clientId);

            if (!playerData.HasValue) { return; }

            lobbyPlayers.Add(new LobbyPlayerState(
                clientId,
                playerData.Value.PlayerName,
                false
            ));
        }

        private void HandleClientDisconnect(ulong clientId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lobbyPlayers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (lobbyPlayers[i].ClientId == clientId)
                {
                    lobbyPlayers.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
        private void ToggleReadyServerRpc(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lobbyPlayers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (lobbyPlayers[i].ClientId == serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId)
                {
                    lobbyPlayers[i] = new LobbyPlayerState(
                        lobbyPlayers[i].ClientId,
                        lobbyPlayers[i].PlayerName,
                        !lobbyPlayers[i].IsReady
                    );
                    Debug.Log("Player" + i + "Ready");
                }
            }

            if (IsEveryoneReady())
            {
                StartGameServerRpc();
            }
        }

        [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
        private void StartGameServerRpc(ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams = default)
        {
            if (serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId != NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId) { return; }

            if (!IsEveryoneReady()) { return; }

            ServerGameNetPortal.Instance.StartGame();
        }

        public void OnLeaveClicked()
        {
            GameNetPortal.Instance.RequestDisconnect();
        }

        public void OnReadyClicked()
        {
            ToggleReadyServerRpc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

I am making my lobby similiar to yours, yours is also probably from DapperDino, and `NetworkList<T>` did'nt work for me the same way it did in the tutorial. Therefore what I did was I used `NetworkVariable<LobbyPlayerState>` instead (provide `LobbyPlayerState` has implemented `INetworkSerializable` interface) for every player (in my case it was only two) and it worked fine.